# load different scripts in index.html based on dev / prod environment in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to load different javascript files based on which environment I'm using. I have created an Angular2 application, which lives inside a MVC app.

In my index.html (_layout.cshtml), I have the following scripts:

```
<script src="~/public/lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->
@*<script src="~/public/dist/js/app.min.js"></script> <!--bundled source-->*@

<script src="~/system.dev.config.js"></script>    
<script>
    System.import('../public/dist/AppComponent/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

This code will load angular2 dependencies and start the application. I want to distinguish between development (when I'm developing on the application) and when it's online in production.

I want to distinguish, so I only load the following files:

**Dev environment:**

```
<script src="~/public/lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->

<script src="~/system.dev.config.js"></script>    
<script>
    System.import('../public/dist/AppComponent/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

**Prod environment:**

```
<script src="~/public/lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->
<script src="~/public/dist/js/app.min.js"></script> <!--bundled source-->
```

Is there any option, so when I am in debug mode it should use the dev scripts and the other way around when in release mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run it without any loader?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@{ 
    #if DEBUG
        <script src="~/public/lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->

        <script src="~/system.dev.config.js"></script>    
        <script>
            System.import('../public/dist/AppComponent/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
        </script>
    #else
        <script src="~/public/lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->
        <script src="~/public/dist/js/app.min.js"></script> <!--bundled source-->
    #endif
}
```

I hope I have helped